# Exclude a subfolder from symlink?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, file-management, symbolic-link

I have a folder I want to symlink (note that this doesn't have to be a symlink specifically, a junction or similar also works) somewhere. In that folder, there are a couple of subfolders and a bunch of files. The folder is often updated with new files added. Is there any way to have this folder symlinked somewhere, excluding a specific subfolder?

Note: I was considering putting all loose files into a subfolder of their own and only linking that and the other desired subfolders. However, this won't work, as these files have to at least appear to be loose and not within a subfolder. I'm specifying this, because if there's a way to have these in a folder but appear to be loose somehow, that would work.

Comment: Would a saved search of the target folder using `FolderPath:NOT C:\Target\ExcludedFolder` work for you? A saved search can be moved from you're Searches folder to wherever you want. Then set the view to `Group by -> Folder Path` (maybe including `Kind: NOT Folder`in the search criteria as well...

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to "symlink all except for ...".

The symlink is nothing but a small text-file that contains the
name of the target folder. It's not possible to add to the
symlink file any more information than that.

The only solution I can see is, as you mentioned,
to organize your files in a separate sub-folder,
then create separate symlinks to each and every
sub-folder except for this one.

Or you will need to create some new folder structure with
a new workflow.